# How to get HAproxy to return next db server's ip address?

Tags: php, mysql, haproxy

I'd like to use HAproxy for checking if my db servers are online, without actually routing the requests through the HAproxy box.  Is there any way I can connect to HAproxy and have it return a DB host IP address?

for example:  from webserver #1 I connect to HAproxy on port 3306.  HAproxy listens on 3306 and echos DB Host #1 from a list of db hosts(round robin). Then from webserver#1 I connect directly to DB host #1.

Comment: If this is part of a real-world application then IMHO the procurement of a backend DB connection should be handled transparently by the proxy. What's your reasoning for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this directly in PHP.

Try something like this:

```
function get_connectable_host(array $hosts, $port, $timeout = 3)
{
    // Optionally randomise the order of the input array
    // This should help to ensure a relatively even distribution over time
    shuffle($hosts);

    // Create some vars
    $socks = $w = array();
    $r = $e = null;
    $flags = STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_ASYNC_CONNECT;

    // Loop over the list of host addresses and send connect attempts to them
    // Store the host address with the created socket resource
    foreach ($hosts as $host) {
        $address = "tcp://$host:$port";
        $sock = stream_socket_client($address, $n, $s, $timeout, $flags);
        $socks[(int) $sock] = array($host, $sock);
        $w[] = $sock;
    }

    // Wait for at least one of the sockets to connect
    if (!stream_select($r, $w, $e, $timeout)) {
        return false; // Nothing connected successfully after the timeout
    }

    // Get the ID of the first socket that connected
    $result = (int) current($w);

    // Loop over the sockets and disconnect them all
    foreach ($socks as $sock) {
        stream_set_blocking($sock[1], 0); // set non-blocking or FIN will block
        stream_socket_shutdown($sock[1], STREAM_SHUT_RDWR);
        fclose($sock[1]);
    }

    // Return the successfully connected host address
    return $socks[$result][0];
}

$hosts = array(
    '192.168.0.1',
    '192.168.0.2',
    '192.168.0.3'
);
$port = 3306;
$timeout = 3; // Max number of seconds to wait for a connection

$hostToUse = get_connectable_host($hosts, $port, $timeout);
```

This should get the IP address of the first host from the supplied array which successfully connects, and crucially will return as soon as a successful connection is made - it will not wait for all the sockets to return and it will only reach the timeout if all of the hosts fail to connect.

Essentially this is doing exactly what you want HAproxy to do for you, directly in PHP.

The really important bits that make this work are [`stream_socket_client()`](http://php.net/stream-socket-client) with `STREAM_CLIENT_ASYNC_CONNECT` and [`stream_select()`](http://php.net/stream-select).

Comment: I was reading the stream_select() manual...From what I understand stream_select() returns after all socks have responded or the timeout time.  I think you are implying the function will return after 1 sock has responded (which is what I want)...I don't see that in the man page.

Comment: @FrancisSnipe Because of the `STREAM_SOCKET_ASYNC_CONNECT` this will work as expected. http://codepad.viper-7.com/uaVuOn <-- note that it doesn't take 3 seconds to return, it happens as soon as one host connects

Answer (score 0):

You could always run this query to figure out the hostname:

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'hostname';
```

https://serverfault.com/a/129646/52951